# Android and Json

Tags: android, arrays, json

[image][image]I have this project and wish to get all names from table like "1" is the first name how code this for all names

```
public void capturarPersonagens(View view) {

    //-- Retrofit
    callPersonagem = service.getPersonagem("1");

    callPersonagem.enqueue(new Callback<Personagem>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Personagem> call, Response<Personagem> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (!call.isCanceled()) {
                    Log.i("Personagem",response.body().getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Best Regards
Pedro Duarte

Comment: Please, share the interface code that defines your `service`. Basically you need to add a new method to that interface that allows you to query all records and not only the one identified by `"1"` as I assume from your call.

Comment: http://www.dontpad.com/20170000

Comment: Sorry i send you the print screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a new method in your Service interface:
The api endpoint `people/?format=json` depends on the actual implementation of your webservice.

```
public interface Service {

    @GET("people/{id}/?format=json")
    Call<Personagem> getPersonagem(@Path("id") String alacazam);

    @GET("people/?format=json")
    Call<ArrayList<Personagem>> getPersonagens();

}
```

Then, you may consume it the same way you did with `getPersonagem`:

```
public void capturarPersonagens(View view) {

    //-- Retrofit
    callPersonagens = service.getPersonagens();

    callPersonagens.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Personagem>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Personagem>> call, Response<ArrayList<Personagem>> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (!call.isCanceled()) {
                    for(Personagem p:response.body()){
                        Log.i("Personagem",p.getName());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Personagem>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("SW", "" + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gero I will fix code later and let you know